# Cannot connect to Mysql From Rails Application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, engineyard

I am having my application and database hosted in EngineYard. Suddenly my application is down. I am getting this error when I looked into the log

> Mysql2::Error: This connection is still waiting for a result, try again once you have the result

I tried to run some read queries from Rails console in Staging. This is working fine. Database queries returns the expected answers.

Also I checked out the Staging branch in local and checked. I could not reproduce the error in my local. So I assume there is no error in the code.

Comment: Did you database went down during that time?

Comment: Its still in that state.

Comment: Did you restarted your rails server?

Comment: @saurabh, krishna is getting error on staging it means it doesn't use `rails server`.

Comment: @krishna, did you try to restart your mysql server on staging or reboot the server instance if restarting mysql doesn't work?

Comment: @saurabh restarting the server worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the App Server worked for me.

Syntax:

```
ey ssh "/engineyard/bin/app_<appname> restart" -e your_env_name --app-servers
```

Reference:
[Engineyard command line: ey web restart not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774795/engineyard-command-line-ey-web-restart-not-working)